# Exposing websocket data through an HTTP endpoint

Tags: node.js, websocket

I'm currenty suscribing to a websocket channel in order to get data that I needs to be consumed by clients using a GET endpoint.

Clients don't need to consume the full data stream, just the last message received.

I thought about storing the data in memory or into a database, and using that data to serve said GET requests, but I suspect that's not the right implementation. Any ideas on how it should be done will be appreciated.

EDIT: I'm not asking for code, just for an idea on what patter should I follow, BTW i'm using express.

Websocket code:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws')
const connection = new WebSocket('wss://ws.bitso.com')
connection.onopen = function () {
  connection.send(JSON.stringify({ action: 'subscribe', book: 'btc_usd', type: 'orders' }))
}
connection.onmessage = function (message) {
  const data = JSON.parse(message.data)
  if (data.type === 'orders' && data.payload) {
    console.log(data)
  }
}
```

Comment: I see no GET endpoint. Just store your received message from the websocket somewhere (array/db/file/map/setc/etc.) and flush the content from your storage when receive a get request. pretty simple.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I did. But I was afraid It was some kind of any pattern.

Comment: Its not perfect, but its does the job. If you need some kind of "caching" from WebSocket (Server send) to pull mechanism (GET) then is absolut ok.

Answer (score 0):

I just stored the data in memory and used that as the return value for my endpoint.